# Encrypting SystemDisk in Alibaba ECS

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

On checking the following documentation for Alibaba Cloud ECS :-

- https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/59643.htm
- https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25499.htm?#CreateInstance
- https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/25517.htm

I see that there's an option to enable encryption for the Data Disks using the following option(s) -

**Set the parameter DataDisk.n.Encrypted (CreateInstance) or Encrypted (CreateDisk) to true.**

However, I don't see a similar option for encrypting the SystemDisk for the ECS instance while creating the instance / or in ModifyDiskAttribute

Is there an option for doing this which is perhaps not documented ?

Answer (score 0):

Missed checking this in the documentation, it's present in the **Limits** section of the following article:

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/59643.htm

**You can only encrypt data disks, not system disks.**

Answer (score 0):

Also, as mentioned **"Data in the instance operating system is not encrypted."** on the following official Alibaba Cloud blog:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/data-encryption-at-storage-on-alibaba-cloud_594581

And I think reason behind it would be that the Encryption on the system disk will slow down the processing capabilities.